# Why this activity is displaying in the new Android version and not in in the old version

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using Android Studio.

only works on Android 9

not working on Android 8 and 7

The issue is from the use of @SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView") // we don't need to support older versions in BRButton.java

how to get this to support older versions ?

E/FirebaseCrash: Firebase Crash Reporting not enabled
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.loafwallet, PID: 6085
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loafwallet/com.breadwallet.presenter.activities.intro.IntroActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
            at com.breadwallet.presenter.activities.intro.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:84)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/CircularPro-Medium.otf
            at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:206)
            at com.breadwallet.tools.manager.FontManager.get(FontManager.java:55)
            at com.breadwallet.tools.manager.FontManager.setCustomFont(FontManager.java:67)
            at com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton.init(BRButton.java:100)
            at com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton.(BRButton.java:79)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414) 
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414) 
            at com.breadwallet.presenter.activities.intro.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:84) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    Application terminated.

IntroActivity.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/BRText"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ctlx_logo"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

<com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton
    android:id="@+id/button_new_wallet"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bread_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bread_margin"
    app:buttonType="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/MenuViewController.createButton"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:isBreadButton="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_recover_wallet"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRButton
    android:id="@+id/button_recover_wallet"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bread_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bread_margin"
    app:buttonType="2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/RecoverWallet.header"
    android:textColor="@color/button_secondary_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:isBreadButton="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<com.breadwallet.presenter.customviews.BRText
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bread_margin"
    android:text="@string/StartViewController.message"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header"
    app:customTFont="CircularPro-Book.otf"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BRText"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/faq_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/faq_dimen"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/faq_dimen"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bread_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bread_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/faq_question_white"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bread_gradient"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
```

IntroActivity.java

```
public static final Point screenParametersPoint = new Point();

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();  // Always call the superclass method first
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
    newWalletButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_new_wallet);
    recoverWalletButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_recover_wallet);
    splashScreen = findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
    setListeners();
    updateBundles();
    faq = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.faq_button);

    faq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!BRAnimator.isClickAllowed()) return;
            BRAnimator.showSupportFragment(app, BRConstants.startView);
        }
    });

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG && BRKeyStore.AUTH_DURATION_SEC != 300) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: BRKeyStore.AUTH_DURATION_SEC != 300");
        BRReportsManager.reportBug(new RuntimeException("AUTH_DURATION_SEC should be 300"), true);
    }
    introActivity = this;

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenParametersPoint);

    if (Utils.isEmulatorOrDebug(this))
        Utils.printPhoneSpecs();

    byte[] masterPubKey = BRKeyStore.getMasterPublicKey(this);
    boolean isFirstAddressCorrect = false;
    if (masterPubKey != null && masterPubKey.length != 0) {
        isFirstAddressCorrect = SmartValidator.checkFirstAddress(this, masterPubKey);
    }
    if (!isFirstAddressCorrect) {
        BRWalletManager.getInstance().wipeWalletButKeystore(this);
    }

    PostAuth.getInstance().onCanaryCheck(this, false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            splashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 1000);

}

private void updateBundles() {
    BRExecutor.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("updateBundle");
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            APIClient apiClient = APIClient.getInstance(IntroActivity.this);
            apiClient.updateBundle();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG, "updateBundle DONE in " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        }
    });
}


private void setListeners() {
    newWalletButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!BRAnimator.isClickAllowed()) return;
            BreadActivity bApp = BreadActivity.getApp();
            if (bApp != null) bApp.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, SetPinActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
        }
    });

    recoverWalletButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!BRAnimator.isClickAllowed()) return;
            BreadActivity bApp = BreadActivity.getApp();
            if (bApp != null) bApp.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, RecoverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    appVisible = true;
    app = this;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    appVisible = false;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

BRButton.java

```
@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView") 
public class BRButton extends Button {
private static final String TAG = BRButton.class.getName();
private static int ANIMATION_DURATION = 30;
private Bitmap shadow;
private Rect shadowRect;
private RectF bRect;
private int width;
private int height;
private int modifiedWidth;
private int modifiedHeight;
private Paint bPaint;
private Paint bPaintStroke;
private int type = 2;
private static final float SHADOW_PRESSED = 0.88f;
private static final float SHADOW_UNPRESSED = 0.95f;
private float shadowOffSet = SHADOW_UNPRESSED;
private static final int ROUND_PIXELS = 16;
private boolean isBreadButton; 

public BRButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public BRButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public BRButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public BRButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    shadow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shadow);
    bPaint = new Paint();
    bPaintStroke = new Paint();
    shadowRect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    bRect = new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100);
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BRButton);
    String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.BRButton_customBFont);
    FontManager.setCustomFont(ctx, this, Utils.isNullOrEmpty(customFont) ? "CircularPro-Medium.otf" : customFont);
    float px16 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //check attributes you need, for example all paddings
    int[] attributes = new int[]{android.R.attr.paddingStart, android.R.attr.paddingTop, android.R.attr.paddingEnd, android.R.attr.paddingBottom, R.attr.isBreadButton, R.attr.buttonType};
     TypedArray arr = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributes);

    isBreadButton = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BRButton_isBreadButton, false);
    int paddingLeft = arr.hasValue(0) ? arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(0, -1) : (int) px16;
    int paddingTop = arr.hasValue(1) ? arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(1, -1) : 0;
    int paddingRight = arr.hasValue(2) ? arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(2, -1) : (int) px16;
    int paddingBottom = arr.hasValue(3) ? arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(3, -1) + (isBreadButton ? (int) px16 : 0) : (isBreadButton ? (int) px16 : 0);

    int type = a.getInteger(R.styleable.BRButton_buttonType, 0);
    setType(type);

    bPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    bPaintStroke.setAntiAlias(true);

    if (isBreadButton) {
        setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_trans));
    }

    setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
    a.recycle();
    arr.recycle();
    final ViewTreeObserver observer = getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (observer.isAlive()) {
                observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            correctTextSizeIfNeeded();
            correctTextBalance();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (isBreadButton) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (getParent() != null) {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            }
            if (type != 3)
                press(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            unPress(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    height = h;

}

private void correctTextSizeIfNeeded() {
    int limit = 100;
    int lines = getLineCount();
    float px = getTextSize();
    while (lines > 1 && !getText().toString().contains("\n")) {
        limit--;
        px -= 1;
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, px);
        lines = getLineCount();
        if (limit <= 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "correctTextSizeIfNeeded: Failed to rescale, limit reached, final: " + px);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void correctTextBalance() {

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (isBreadButton) {
        shadowRect.set(5, height / 4, width - 5, (int) (height * shadowOffSet));
        modifiedWidth = width - 10;
        modifiedHeight = height - height / 4 - 5;
        bRect.set(5, 5, modifiedWidth, modifiedHeight + 5);
        canvas.drawBitmap(shadow, null, shadowRect, null);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(bRect, ROUND_PIXELS, ROUND_PIXELS, bPaint);
        if (type == 2 || type == 3)
            canvas.drawRoundRect(bRect, ROUND_PIXELS, ROUND_PIXELS, bPaintStroke);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);

}

public void setType(int type) {
    if (type == 3) press(1);
    this.type = type;

    if (type == 1) { //blue
        bPaint.setColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.button_primary_normal));
        setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else if (type == 2) { //gray stroke
        bPaintStroke.setColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.extra_light_gray));
        bPaintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(Utils.getPixelsFromDps(getContext(), 1));
        setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
        bPaint.setColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.button_secondary));
        bPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    } else if (type == 3) { //blue strokeww
        bPaintStroke.setColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.button_primary_normal));
        bPaintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(Utils.getPixelsFromDps(getContext(), 1));
        setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.button_primary_normal));
        bPaint.setColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.button_secondary));
        bPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
    invalidate();
}

private void press(int duration) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 0.96f,
            1f, 0.96f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
    scaleAnim.setDuration(duration);
    scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
    scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillBefore(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

    ValueAnimator shadowAnim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(SHADOW_UNPRESSED, SHADOW_PRESSED);
    shadowAnim.setDuration(duration);
    shadowAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            shadowOffSet = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            invalidate();
        }
    });

    startAnimation(scaleAnim);
    shadowAnim.start();

}

private void unPress(int duration) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(
            0.96f, 1f,
            0.96f, 1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
    scaleAnim.setDuration(duration);
    scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
    scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());``
    scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillBefore(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

    ValueAnimator shadowAnim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(SHADOW_PRESSED, SHADOW_UNPRESSED);
    shadowAnim.setDuration(duration);
    shadowAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            shadowOffSet = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            invalidate();
        }
    });

    startAnimation(scaleAnim);
    shadowAnim.start();
}
}
```

Comment: it's because of your `font`. You should post your `BRButton` code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simply saying Android Studio was unable to find the following assets file

```
fonts/CircularPro-Medium.otf
```

Confirm that the file exist in your fonts folder inside your assets directory and rebuild your project.